# Is there a way that I can set more than one property in a list to "" or null at the same time with a .ForEach?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code that works but I would like to simplify it. I tried to string each .ForEach together but seems like that's not possible. Can someone suggest how I can combine these:

```
            phraseSources
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(i => i.JishoExists = "");
            phraseSources
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(i => i.CommonWord = "");
            phraseSources
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(i => i.JishoWanikani = null);
            phraseSources
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(i => i.JishoJlpt = null);
```

Comment: btw about `ForEach()`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of `ForEach` first parameter is `Action<T>` which mean you can use a delegate method with one parameter.

you can try to use big parentheses on the delegate parameter.

```
phraseSources
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => {
        i.JishoExists = "";
        i.CommonWord = "";
        i.JishoWanikani = null;
        i.JishoJlpt = null;
    });
```

Comment: This will not work well with structs. I would risk saying that `ToList().ForEeach` is a bit of an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `foreach` (not `ForEach`) is the best tool for this job.

```
foreach(var i in phraseSources)
{
   i.JishoExists = "";
   i.CommonWord = "";
   i.JishoWanikani = null;
   i.JishoJlpt = null;
}
```

---

`ToList().ForEach` can lead to unexpected results. Consider the following example.

```
public class XClass {public string A {get; set;}}
public struct XStruct {public string A {get; set;}}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var array1 = new []{new XClass{A="One"}, new XClass{A="Two"}};
    var array2 = new []{new XStruct{A="One"}, new XStruct{A="Two"}};

    array1.ToList().ForEach( x => x.A = "XXX");
    array2.ToList().ForEach( x => x.A = "XXX");

    Console.WriteLine(array2[0].A); // Ooops: it's still "One"
}
```